# Adding additional items below the twitter bootstrap bs-docs-sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so what im trying to do at the moment is add a few more things below the bs-docs-sidebar for twitter bootstrap. Im currently using this code

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span3 bs-docs-sidebar">
<div class="row-fluid">
     <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix">
        <li><a href="#typography"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#code"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tables"><i class="icon-chevron-right disabled"></i> Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a id="contribute" href="#forms"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> item 4</a>          
        <li><a id="contribute" href="#buttons"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> item </li> 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="well affix">
        <h4>Big Heading</h4>
        <div class="btn-group btn-block">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">option 1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">option 2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">option 3</button>
        </div>
        <h4 class="pagination-centered">Or</h4>
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Alternative</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

but the position of the well, is not below the nav menu, it is stuck to the bottom of the page, and cut-off because the well contents seem to be pushing it out of range, is there a way to affix to the bottom of the nav menu instead?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide a functional http://jsfiddle.net demonstration of the problem you're having? If we could see it, it would make it much easier tow ork out.

Comment: bs-docs-sidebar is not part of standard bootstrap download if I'm correct. It is customized css on bootstrap docs site.